# How to add a description to input file accept in HTML?

Tags: html, file, input, file-extension

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyBKLK

HTML:

```
<input type="file" accept=".test">
```

The file dialog shows only files with the `.test` extension. However, often file dialogs show an accompanying description of the file type, like "Test file (*.test)". Is it possible to add such a description to the file extension?

Here are a couple of examples: In MS Word one will get "Word-Documents (*.docx)" in the filter drop down. In a browser, for example, "XML Files (*.xml)". Similarly, I would like to have the drop down show "Test file (*.test)", or similar. But the code above will show only "*.bec" in the file extension filter.

Comment: could you explain a bit more?  I have tested file upload wizard by default checks for test files. What do you want exactly???

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt I have added a couple of examples. Does that help?

Comment: Have you tried “description/type”

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Now I have. I tried `Test File/.test`  and `Test File/test` but none worked. Was that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Sorry did not work.

Comment: Don’t think you can: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp